# How do you differentiate between rms and peak voltage?

Tags: circuit-analysis, electrical, rms

[image]

In the circuit above I've been asked to calculate the average power absorbed by the 10 Ω resistor. I managed to calculate a value for \$V_0=40\sqrt2\,\angle{-25}\$.

But I'm not sure if this is peak or rms voltage. I've spoken to some people and they say that the rms value is simply \$40\sqrt2\$, which doesn't really make sense to me, and I've spoken to other people who say to follow the \$\frac{V_p}{\sqrt2}\$ formula, which makes a lot more sense to me.

I'm not really sure who to believe, so I've come here seeking help.

Comment: You should just ask the instructor for clarification.

Comment: I love how the title of your question and your username form a pun.

Comment: That was a **mean** thing to say @MarcusMüller lol

Answer (score 5):

Noting this: -

[image]

When your circuit says this (my words in red): -

[image]

In the absence of any other information, AC voltages are always presumed to be RMS.

See [this Wiki reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor#Circuit_laws): -

> *the magnitudes of the voltage and current phasors V and I are the RMS
>   values of the voltage and current, respectively).*

And...

> *I managed to calculate a value*

Well, unless you have decided to convert to sinusoidal peak values, you will have calculated a value based on an input of 8 volts RMS.

Answer (score 3):

RMS of a sinusoid is the square root of 2 smaller than the peak amplitude (\$\frac{V_m}{\sqrt2}\$ ).This [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) should help.

In power system analysis texts we almost always use rms magnitudes.  e.g. A current of 5@45 degrees amps is 5A rms or 7.07A peak.